# Strange change in struct members

Tags: c

i ve tried almost everything but i cant solve this problem. I have a struct:

```
typedef struct{
char firstname[15];
char lastname[20];
char status[1];
char dateOfBirth[10];   
} Rec;
```

and a main:

```
int main()
{    
Rec rec;
strcpy(rec.status,"M");
strcpy(rec.dateOfBirth,"14-11-2000");
strcpy(rec.firstname,"Peter");
strcpy(rec.lastname,"Something");

printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n", rec.status,rec.dateOfBirth,rec.firstname,rec.lastname);

return 0;
}
```

So this, should print -> M, 14-11-2000, Peter, Something ..but it doesnt!
It prints -> M14-11-2000, 14-11-2000, Peter, Something.

In other words the "status" member gets "corrupted".
I noticed that if i change the order of the struct's data , the output changes but there is always a data that gets corrupted.

Is there anything wrong in the way that i define my struct? Thx!

Comment: "M" is actually 2 characters, there is the "M" and the terminating null

Answer (score 10):

You need to make the char arrays 1 byte longer to allow for the null terminator. In particular, the `status` and `dateOfBirth` fields should be 2 and 11 bytes respectively based on how you are using them.  `strcpy` copies the given data plus 1 null terminator byte. Without that, the strcpy ends up writing one byte past that member (which would likely be the very next member in this case since char arrays would likely end up with one byte alignment).

Comment: Oh i see, thank you so much. i've been trying for hours to find this !

Comment: Also note that [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) is a safer version of `strcpy` as it will make sure it never copies too much.

Comment: @Kninnug: Yes that is a good point.  Sadly, though, strncpy also has issues (mainly that it does not guarantee the result to be null terminated).  I finally ended up writing my own strcpy function that guarantees null termination and works the same on all platforms.  Not as fast as CRT strcpy functions, but the added safety and conformity in all builds makes it worth it.

Comment: @MarkWilkins agreed, I did say safer, not safest ;). For one project I'm using `struct`s with a size and a (w)char pointer of that size, so I don't need null-termination at all. A bit FORTRAN-like, but I believe it's the safest way (as long as size & the size of the pointer match, of course). I had to rewrite CRT functionality as well, but it does allow strings with `\0`s in them.

Answer (score 6):

In C a string is a char array terminated with a 0-byte, so your char arrays need to be one byte longer.

Answer (score 3):

Your `char` arrays `status` and `dateOfBirth` are too short; you need to account for the terminating null character.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your char arrays are missing null terminators (the status buff doesn't have space for one). `printf` continues printing til it encounters a null terminator, it does no bounds checking.

Comment: String literals are always null terminated in C, manually putting '\0' at the end is not needed.